# Update entity, которое содержит коллекции, выдает ошибку org.hibernate.QueryException: collections not assignable in update statements

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, запрос

При инициализации проэкта сразу выдает ошибку org.hibernate.QueryException: collections not assignable in update statements. Подскажите, как правильно обновить объект, который содержит в себе коллекции?

Есть данный объект `@Entity

```
@Table(
    name = "item"
)
public class Item {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private long id;

@Column(name = "number_model")
private String modelNumber;

@Column(name = "name")
private String modelName;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
@JoinTable(name="item_place",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="item_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="place_id", referencedColumnName="id")
)
private List<Place> placeList;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
@JoinTable(name = "item_style",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "item_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "style_id")
)
private Style modelStyle;`
```

Как правильно обновить данный объект, вдруг если данные я какие-то в нем хочу поменять в базе?

Comment: Что там написано надо перевести сначала

Comment: подробностей бы

Comment: есть объект вот такой http://prntscr.com/mnah18 с разынми полями, так вот из-за того, что внутри него содержится коллекция, то используя данный метод http://prntscr.com/mnahdq для обновления, из-за этого не собирается проэкт, пишет данную ошибку, что указано в заголовке